# Syncing Assets to AWS cloudfront with asset_sync gem

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, heroku, amazon-cloudfront

syncing assets with s3 via `asset_sync` works seamlessly.

Is there a way to sync to cloudfront in a similar manner?

Answer (score 1):

You probably wouldn't need to do anything special here. Cloudfront can be configured to "just work" for whatever happens to be in a given bucket. So you could use asset sync to keep things together and allow cloudfront to just pass all requests through to the synced bucket. You can see a bit about how to setup a distribution for cloudfront to point to a particular bucket here: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudFront/latest/DeveloperGuide/GettingStarted.html